# Getx Flutter while updating value throwing null error

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Data Model

```
class DataModel {
  Book? book;
  DataModel({
     this.book,
  });
}

class Book {
  String author;
  Book({
    required this.author,
  });
}
```

Getx Controller

```
class BookController extends GetxController{
   var dataModel = DataModel().obs;
  updateAuthor(){
    dataModel.value.book!.author = "";
  }
}
```

While updating author Getx throwing " null checked used on a null value"

After changing the function to this

```
  updateAuthor(){
    dataModel.value.book?.author = "";
  }
```

It is not updating the value, making it null.

Also tried with update method unable to update the value with this type of data model.Class inside class.

I am just trying to update the author but unable to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I will explain what you did wrong,

First, you made an object of `DataModel`.

```
   var dataModel = DataModel().obs;
```

this `dataModel` have a `book` property which you marked it with a `?` so you made it nullable.

so at this point this:

```
dataModel.value.book == null ; // true
```

you didn't assign a real `Book` instance to the book property, so it's `null`, so this line:

```
dataModel.value.book!.author = ""; // will throw an error
```

because `dataModel.value.book` is `null`.

what you need to assign a new `Book()` object to the book property like this, specifying the `author` property that `Book()`

```
  updateAuthor(){
  dataModel.value.book = Book(author: "");
  dataModel.refresh();
  }
```

now we have a real `Book` object assigned to `book`, this will fix the null error you got.

Comment: Thanks, Gwhyyy this was only my mistake.